# dhclient ipv6 on startup

Tags: networking, dhcp, ipv6

I need my servers to fetch an IPv6 address using dhclient on startup.  I can run `dhclient -6 ens18` to get an IP, but can't get it to do that on startup.  Adding it to crontab @reboot didn't work.  Editing `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yml` and adding `dhcp6: true` didn't work either.

How can I get ubuntu 18.04 server to fetch an ipv6 address using dhcp on startup on the interface ens18?

Comment: When you start and there is no IPv6 address, are the any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep -i ipv6` Were there any errors at: `sudo netplan generate` or: `sudo netplan apply`?